Using MATCH Function to Get Number of Column With First Cell Greater Than Zero but Ignoring Non-Numbers
I've figured out how to use MATCH to return the number of the column of the first number greater than X. See the image (formula I put in cell G3).

However, when I try something similar – the formula I put in G4 was:
=MATCH(TRUE,B4:E4>0.5,0)
It returns 1 (see the result in G4 in the image) because the text in cell B4 (Apple) "counts" as being greater than 0.5. I want it to ignore anything that is not a number and return to me the number of the column of the first cell with a number greater than 0. That means it would skip over B4, because it is text, and return 2 because C4 contains the number 8, which is greater than 0.5 (when I use this on my other spreadsheet, I want it to be greater than 0 rather than 0.5).
If anyone can point me in the right direction, that'd be fantastic.

I do not see any image to your post.

So you have another condition, e.g. ISNUMBER(B4:E4). Simply multiply it by the first condition. Keep in mind the operator precedence (first condition in parentheses). When both conditions are met, multiplying them will no longer be a boolean: TRUE*TRUE = 1.

Is this what you are trying? =MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(B4:E4)*(B4:E4>0.5),0)

@VBasic2008 I think you should post it as an answer?

Siddharth Rout's solution worked! But I must confess that I don't understand how it works.

And also, what if instead of I wanted it to return the column number, I wanted it to return the number itself (in this case, the number 8)?

@BobSlydell, combine INDEX with MATCH to get the value itself: =INDEX(B4:E4,MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(B4:E4)*(B4:E4>0.5),0))

Awesome, thanks, that worked perfectly! Now what if I wanted to find the SECOND number over zero rather than the first (and the third, fourth, fifth, and sixth)? I tried making the first argument of the MATCH formula 2 as opposed to 1 but it just gave me a #N/A, even though there was a second number in the range (I'm working with a dataset much bigger and much more complicated than the one in the screenshot--I just used here the one I created for the screenshot for the sake of ease).

The 1 in the formula doesn't represent the 1st match in the row. It represents the lookup value for the MATCH function. The result of the MATCH function evaluates to the column index of the row B4:E4, the index of the left-most cell, where the condition ISNUMBER(B4:E4)*(B4:E4>0.5) is equal to 1. For example, if the row contains {0,5,"B",1}, ISNUMBER(B4:E4)*(B4:E4>0.5) evaluates to {0,1,0,1} where the ones represent the conditions met. Therefore, MATCH will return 2, the index (position) of the first (left-most) match, while INDEX will return 5 from 2nd cell.

@VBasic2008 understood. So to use the numbers from your example (where the first row contains {0,5,"B",1}, if I wanted it to return the value of the SECOND cell for which the condition was true (the cell is a number that is greater than 0.5), which, in this case, is 1 (the fourth cell in that row, because 0 is less than 0.5 and "B" is a character), how would I do that?

In MS365, you could use =INDEX(FILTER(B4:E4,ISNUMBER(B4:E4)*(B4:E4>0.5)),2) or using the LET function =LET(data,B4:E4,INDEX(FILTER(data,ISNUMBER(data)*(data>0.5)),2)). Otherwise, it's something like =INDEX(B4:E4,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(B4:E4)*(B4:E4>0.5)=1,COLUMN(B4:E4)-COLUMN(B4)+1),2)). In the formulas above, the 2 represents the 2nd match. Note that it is more efficient to retrieve the first match without the SMALL or the FILTER functions. Also, in MS365, for the 1st match, you would use =XLOOKUP(1,ISNUMBER(B4:E4)*(B4:E4>0.5),B4:E4) possibly improved with the LET function.

@BobSlydell, your question is already answered. Instead of continuously changing your requirements in comments, create new questions.
